How to Display User Profile Data in Flutter's Chat Screen from Firestore?
I'm developing a Flutter application where users can chat with each other. I've successfully implemented user authentication and profile creation. Now, I'm trying to display the user's profile data, including their image and name, in the chat screen's app bar. Additionally, I want to show the last seen status of the user.
Here's what I've done so far:
Created a Firestore collection named "userProfile" containing documents with fields for imageLink and name.
When a user signs up, their profile data is uploaded to the "userProfile" collection.
In the ContactsPage, I display the user's image and name fetched from the "userProfile" collection.
User profile page code
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/screens/home_screen.dart'; // Ensure this import is correct

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenRoute = "userProfile";
  final String email;
  const UserProfile({Key? key, required this.email}) : super(key: key); 

  @override
  State<UserProfile> createState() => _UserProfileState();
}

class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  File? file;
  String? url;
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  var emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<void> getImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      file = File(image.path);
      var imageName = basename(image.path);
      var refStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(imageName);
      await refStorage.putFile(file!);
      url = await refStorage.getDownloadURL();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  Future<void> saveUserProfile(BuildContext context) async {
    String uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
    if (url != null && _nameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('signup')
          .doc(widget.email)
          .collection('user_profile')
          .doc(uid) // You can use another identifier if needed
          .set({
        'name': _nameController.text,
        'image_link': url,
      });
      // Navigate to the home screen after saving the profile
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, Homescreen.screenroute); // Ensure the correct reference to HomeScreen
    } else {
      // Handle error, either url or name is not provided
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Please provide both name and image."),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //String email=widget.email!;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: const Text(
          "Profile Info",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Text(
              "Please provide your name and an optional profile photo",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.5),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(26),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_rounded),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: getImage,
              child: const Text("Upload Image"),
            ),
            if (url != null)
              Image.network(
                url!,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _nameController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Type your name here",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Icon(
                  Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => saveUserProfile(context),
              child: const Text("Save Profile"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


contacts page code
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/Chatpage.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/ContactSearchDelegate.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/individual_page.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = "ContactsPage";
  const ContactsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {
  Set<Contact> _contacts = {};
  bool _contactsLoaded = false;
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> data = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> userProfileData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _getContacts(); 
    _askPermissions();
  }

 Future<void> _getContacts() async {
  String currentUserEmail = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email ?? '';
  
  // Fetch user profiles from Firestore excluding the current user
  QuerySnapshot userProfilesSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('signup')
      .where(FieldPath.documentId, isNotEqualTo: currentUserEmail)
      .get();
  
  for (var doc in userProfilesSnapshot.docs) {
    String userId = doc.id;
    QuerySnapshot userProfileSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('signup')
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('user_profile')
        .get();
    setState(() {
      data.addAll(userProfileSnapshot.docs);
    });
  }
}


  

  Future<void> uploadContactToFirestore(Contact contact) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      String userId = user.email!;
      CollectionReference userCollection = firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('contacts');

      String phoneNumber = '';
      if (contact.phones != null && contact.phones!.isNotEmpty) {
        phoneNumber = contact.phones!.first.value!;
      }
      // Check if the contact with the same phone number already exists
      QuerySnapshot existingContacts = await userCollection.where('phoneNumber', isEqualTo: phoneNumber).get();
      if (existingContacts.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        print('Contact already exists in Firestore: ${contact.displayName}');
        return; // Do not upload the contact again
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> contactData = {
        'name': contact.displayName ?? '',
        'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
        'lastSeen': Timestamp.now(),
      };

      await userCollection.add(contactData);

      print('Contact uploaded to Firestore: ${contact.displayName}');
    } else {
      print('User not logged in');
    }
  }

  void navigateToIndividualPage(Contact contact) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      Individualpage.screenroute,
      arguments: {'title': contact.displayName ?? ''},
    );
  }

  Future<void> _askPermissions() async {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted && permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
    }

    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _loadContacts();
    } else {
      _handleInvalidPermissions(permissionStatus);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _loadContacts() async {
    List<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
    setState(() {
      _contacts = contacts.toSet(); // Convert to Set to remove duplicates
      _contactsLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  void _handleInvalidPermissions(PermissionStatus permissionStatus) {
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Access to contacts denied'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    } else if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Contact data not available on device'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70.0),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF075E54),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Don't show the leading button
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'Select contacts',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text('${_contacts.length} Contacts', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54, fontSize: 15)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 40,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      onPressed: _contactsLoaded
                          ? () {
                              showSearch(
                                context: context,
                                delegate: ContactSearchDelegate(
                                  _contacts.toList(),
                                  onContactSelected: navigateToIndividualPage,
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          : null,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 40,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        children: <Widget>[
          // Display user profiles from Firestore
          for (var doc in data)
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?)?.containsKey('image_link') ?? false
           ? NetworkImage((doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['image_link'])
                    : AssetImage('images/default-avatar.png') as ImageProvider,
              ),
              title: Text(
                doc.get('name') ?? 'No name',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              //subtitle: Text(doc.get('email') ?? doc.get('phone') ?? 'No Contact Info'),
               onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(
            context,
            ChatPage.screenRoute,
            arguments: {
              'name': doc.get('name'),
              'image_link': (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['image_link'],
              // Pass other necessary user data
            },
          );
        },
            ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color: Color(0xFF25D366),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              'New Group',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color: Color(0xFF25D366),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person_add),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              'New Contact',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          // Add your contacts dynamically here
          for (var contact in _contacts)
            ListTile(
              leading: Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  color: Color(0xFF25D366),
                ),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  // backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                  //   'images/default_avatar.jpg', // Default avatar for contacts
                  // ),
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(
                contact.displayName ?? 'No Name', 
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(contact.phones?.isNotEmpty == true ? contact.phones!.first.value! : 'No Number'),
              onTap: ()async {
                    await uploadContactToFirestore(contact);
                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                      context,
                      Individualpage.screenroute,
                      arguments: {'title': '${contact.displayName}'},
                    );
                  },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Now, I'm working on the ChatScreen, where users can chat with each other. I want to display the user's profile image and name in the app bar of the ChatScreen, along with their last seen status.
Here are my questions:
How can I fetch and display the user's profile image and name from Firestore in the app bar of the ChatScreen?
What's the best approach to implement the last seen status feature?
Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.
to fetch and display the user's profile image and name from Firestore in the app bar of the ChatScreen?

You can use snapshot Listener for that particular document and use state management to make it available everywhere without making another request to firestore. All the widget can very easily share the state even across different screens. The best example is StreamProvider in Riverpod state management and can dynamically create state for various user with their userid via .family and just set the provider as autodispose such that when it is not in use the subscription to snapshot is disposed and no resources is wasted.
